# How to install extensions in Chrome without a Google Account?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am trying to install a [free extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-title/fepbnnnkkadjhjahcafoaglimekefifl) in Google Chrome, but whenever I click "Add To Chrome", I am asked to sign in to a Google account. This has never happened before, and I do not want to use an account just to install an extension. This problem is occurring for all extensions. How can I install extensions without signing in?

Comment: I just went to their web site, where they had a direct download to the extension off their github.

Comment: Just use the direct link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/readium/fepbnnnkkadjhjahcafoaglimekefifl

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's not for downloading, it's for installing/adding!

Comment: Seems like Google Chrome/Web Store doesn't require one to login currently/anymore to install extensions (v36.0.1985.143).

Comment: In Chrome now you'll be told you cant do it unless you first enable a flag  1) visit from the address bar chrome://flags  2) search 'exensions' 3) Set 'Extensions Menu Access Control' to 'Enable'  4) They'll likely keep renaming this as they are jerks. 5) You'll now be able to drag the extension file saved from https://crxviewer.com/ or similar onto the page

Comment: @Evolve this didn't quite work for me (using ungoogled Chromium), but was a good starter. I succeeded by downloading the ZIP from crxviewer, unpack it into an empty directory, then enabled developer settings in extensions and loaded the extension as "unpacked" (after having applied your changes). Some more hints can be [found here](https://github.com/NeverDecaf/chromium-web-store) – most likely drag'n'drop will work after having set `chrome://flags/#extension-mime-request-handling` to "Always prompt for install", as suggested there. Thanks for your hints, wouldn't have managed without!

Comment: PS: Bingo, thanks to the last mentioned setting being added to the equation, I now can directly install extensions (via crxviewer) without manually unpacking them first. I'm prompted to install – and it installs.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You now seem to need sign in to a Google account to install any extensions/add-ons from [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions).

[image: Sign in to Chrome. Sign in to get your bookmarks, history, and settings on all your devices.]

But you can still install an extension without logging in to a Google account by doing the following:

1. **Find the ID for the extension** you want to install. You can see it in the URL on in Chrome Web Store.

   For example [Adblock Plus extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb?hl=en-US) has an URL like:

   ```
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb?hl=en-US
   ```

   The ID we want is the long string of random characters like `cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb` in the URL above.
2. **Download the extension package**, a `.crx` file.

   You can do this by using this URL with the `<ID>` part replaced by the ID from above:

   ```
   https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D<ID>%26uc
   ```

   For the Adblock Plus `.crx` [the URL would be](https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dcfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb%26uc):

   ```
   https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dcfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb%26uc
   ```

   You will get a warning about that extensions cannot be added from this site, but you can ignore that, the `.crx` will be downloaded anyway.
3. **Go to your extensions page** in Google Chrome. You can find it in the Tools -> Extensions menu or by using the following URL:

   ```
   chrome://extensions
   ```
4. **Drag and drop** the downloaded extension `.crx` file you just downloaded in to this window to install it.

   [image: Drag and drop to install extension]

And you're done.

You could also use helpers like [Chrome Extension Downloader](http://chrome-extension-downloader.com/) to download the `.crx` file.

Comment: In newer version drag and drop in Step 4 does not work. It says `This can only be added from the Chrome Web Store`. Workaround for this is rename `.crx` extension of the downloaded file to `.zip` and extract the file. Then in chrome extensions page enable developer mode and click on 'Load unpacked extension'. Then select the extracted folder.

Comment: @Nufail, wow, so they want to make it even more complicated. That's just great... (Will update this when I have the time, unless someone else does that first.)

Comment: And for those who don't have drag and drop support, just extract the crx file with 7zip, activate developer mode in the extension panel and load extension from folder. Cheers!

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Any update to this? Im just trying to get the .crx file, not install it.

Comment: Followed Nufail's suggestion. Got error about _metadata folder. Renamed it to metadata. Then, it worked.

Comment: Step 2 does not work anymore, it just shows a blank page

Comment: Open chrome://extensions/ and drag the .crx file into that tab.

Answer (score 6):

<sup>Summing up information collected in the comments on the question itself:</sup>

For **Ungoogled Chromium**, this is how it worked out for me (steps 1-3 by [Evolve](https://superuser.com/users/17366/evolve)):

#### One-time Preparations

1. visit from the address bar: `chrome://flags`
2. search 'exensions'
3. Set 'Extensions Menu Access Control' to 'Enable'
4. clear the search, then set `chrome://flags/#extension-mime-request-handling` to 'Always prompt for install'

#### Install process (without login)

1. search for the extension you want to install (see [this answer](/a/684756/143340) for details)
2. copy it's ID (e.g. `cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm` for uBlock Origin)
3. paste it to the text input at [crxviewer.com](https://crxviewer.com/) and choose to download as extension
4. once the download is completed, you should see a popup prompting you to install or save. Simply hit 'install', and you should be done.

Extensions will show up as "not from Chrome Web Store" in `chrome://extensions/`, and <s>I'm not sure</s> to my experience they will **not** update automatically (you will have to repeat steps 2-4 of the "Install process" to do that manually).

If the above for some reason should not work out, you can still download from crxviewer as ZIP, unzip to an empty directory, enable developer mode in `chrome://extensions/`, and load the extension as unpacked. That's how I started – so it might be needed to have developer mode enabled as well.

---

More hints can e.g. be [found here](https://github.com/NeverDecaf/chromium-web-store). I didn't install this extension as I didn't want direct ties to Google; if you don't care about that, installing the [Chromium Web Store extension](https://github.com/NeverDecaf/chromium-web-store) might make the process much easier for you if you're on Chromium.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the announcement about locking installation of Chrome extensions so that they can only be installed via the chrome store: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/d35tIyH8dVM%5B1-25-false%5D

They also say:

> What if I want to run non-web store extensions? 
>   Advanced users can continue to use our [Dev](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) & [Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html) channels to run any extension. Please note that these channels are updated very regularly, and may contain features and bug fixes that are actively being developed.

The easiest way around is to just not use the Chrome Web Store, or just don't use Chrome.

Chrome is completely useless for me if I can't install extensions. I will not create a google account just so I can download from the chrome store. This looks much more like forcing millions of Chrome users to create google accounts than actually do anything about security.

Comment: I agree. It's Google BS.

Comment: Firefox is heading the same way - https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2015/02/17/firefox-to-get-a-walled-garden-for-browser-extensions-mozilla-to-be-sole-arbiter/ "In the second half of 2015, it says, Firefox will require all browser extensions to be digitally signed." 
I have already switched to Palemoon and Dragon. RIP Firefox, it was your extensions that made you great.

Comment: @Underverse: That's different. Having signed extensions is a good thing, but forcing you to sign-up and use Google's servers for any kind of installation is not.

Comment: Is it possible to just download the crx without having to log in?

Comment: I'd agree with Underverse's answer, "...or just don't use Chrome".  As long as Google persists in their arrogance, we shouldn't support them.